# Screenshot div in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html2canvas

Im trying to capture a div that's contained in a lightning component, using Html2canvas, but im getting an error.

This is my component :

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="VM_VFC_ComparisonController">
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/VM_SLDS/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.min.css" scripts="/resource/jquery,/resource/html2canvas"/> 

    <div id="ComparisonPage">        
        Elements to screenshot 
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

and this is the controller code :

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('ComparisonPage'),{ 
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        //show image
        var myCanvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas_id');
        var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,270,350); // Or at whatever offset you like
        };
        console.log('img >> ', canvas.toDataURL());
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't any html element with id `my_canvas_id`. Is it supposed to be rendered in the `ComparisonPage` div?

Comment: Also you do not need to include slds in the `styles=...`

Comment: And, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: I have an element with the id my_canvas_id I just wanted to show only the concerned code.

Comment: The error im getting is in this line of the html2canvas javascript file :
documentClone.open();
it says that the document is undefined,
i know that in lightning we cannot access the document but i don't know how to replace it

Comment: This is the error text: /resource/html2canvas:756 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined